# VIM save-execute-reload file

Tags: vim

While I am editing a file I occasionally want to save it, execute a command that may modify the file, then reload it. I.e. First `:w`, then `:!something  %`, and later `:e`

Can I somehow automate this so I can simply type a command that does all of the above three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Try this:

```
:command! -nargs=+ Doit :w | :exe "!" . <q-args> . " %" | :e
```

Or if you just want to "hard code" the command:

```
:command! Doit :w | :exe "!something %" | :e
```

Note that user-defined Vim commands must always start with an uppercase letter. For reference:

```
:help :command
:help <q-args>
:help :execute
:help :|
```